# How do I multiply a smaler dataframe to evy row of another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with the same column name but different amount of rows

```
data=ones((100,2))
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = ('a','b'))

df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[5,6,7,8,9],'b':[6,6,6,6,6]})
```

What  I want to do is,  multiply df2 to df1 but the df2 to repeat every 5 rows to the df1

What I did is

```
df6=pd.DataFrame(columns=('a','b'))
for x in range(0,90,5):    
    df6=df6.append(df2*df1.iloc[x:x+5,:])
```

But it only  works for the first 5 rows an then I only get NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding .values to your indexed dataframe your code works.

```
df6=df6.append(df2.multiply(df1.iloc[x:x+5,:].values))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, but what is the .values doing?

Comment: @user1181237 https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values

Answer (score 1):

You can do `reindex` then `mul`

```
df1 = df1.mul(df2.reindex(df1.index%5).values)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, but I don´t really understand the code